# Is this intentional behavior of undefined when using .sort()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, undefined, reverse

I was trying to solve a Codewars Kata that requires a 47 bytes code solution for reversing an array of any[] type. The catch is - you cannot use `.reverse()`. As a solution I came up with using `.sort()` like this:

```
const reverse = (a: any[]) => a.sort(() => -1);
```

It works well, but I encountered a problem with `undefined`. So an array like this `[undefined, 0]` will be reversed as expected into `[0, undefined]`, but if you try to reverse `[0, undefined]` with this method it just returns the same array back.

```js
const reverse = (a: any[]) => a.sort(() => -1);

console.log(reverse([undefined, 0]));
console.log(reverse([0, undefined]));
```

I don't quite understand how it works behind the scene, after all I am not even comparing anything, just return -1 to reverse it. Any ideas about this behavior?

Comment: The behaviour is expected. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description

Comment: Your comparator does not obey the requirements of a consistent comparator, so this wouldn't be a valid solution anyway - it happened to reverse the inputs you tried, on the implementation you tried, but the spec doesn't promise what order `Array.prototype.sort` will produce for inconsistent comparators.

Comment: (1) Your comparison function is not valid, so the results are going to be erratic. "[The sort order is implementation-defined](https://tc39.es/ecma262/2023/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-sortindexedproperties) if SortCompare is not a consistent comparator for the elements of items." (2) `undefined` values are always put at the end, as @Phil noted.

Comment: With a longer array, your invalid comparator function could possibly cause a sort routine to go into an infinite loop, because there's no guarantee that the elements to be compared are passed in the same order if the comparator is called for them twice. Your code will tell `sort()` that 2 is less than 3 and also that 3 is less than 2, which can be a problem.

Comment: All iteration problems can be solved using `.reduce()`. In this  case `x.reduce((a,v) => [v, ... a], [])`